# A modular which is not a metrizing modular (hence not an F-norm)?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm taking the terminology from Rolewicz's 1985 Metric Linear Spaces.

Given a complex vector space $X$, a modular $m$ is any function $m:X\to[0,+\infty]$ satisfying the following for all $x,y\in X$ and $\lambda,\eta\in\mathbb{C}$:

(1) $m(x)=0\iff x=0$;

(2) $m(\lambda x)=m(x)$ whenever $|\lambda|=1$;

(3) $m(\lambda x+\eta y)\leq m(x)+m(y)$ whenever $\lambda,\eta\geq0$ satisfy $\lambda+\eta=1$;

(4) $m(\lambda_n x)\to 0$ provided $\lambda_n\to 0$ and $m(x)<+\infty$.

Further we call it a metrizing modular if $m$ satisfies

(5) $m(\lambda x_n)\to 0$ provided $m(x_n)\to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$.

An F-norm is simply a norm but rather than homogeneity we have $\|\lambda x\|\leq\|x\|$ for $|\lambda|\leq 1$, and we must assume (4) above (and these collectively imply (5) above).

My question is if (1)-(4) imply (5) or not.  I suspect not but can't find an example of a function satisfying (1)-(4) but not (5).  Rolewicz doesn't provide one.  I don't know if it's going to be something really pathological or if I'm missing something obvious.  My idea was to have $m$ be identically $+\infty$ somewhere and pretty normal elsewhere but that messed up (2).

Comment: I don't see how the F-norm homogeneity and (4) imply (5). Also, the axiom (3) seems a bit weird with that $\lambda+\eta=1$, one would expect a similar formula that also enables both $\lambda=\eta=1$.

Comment: As for the F-norm homogeneity and (4) implying (5), it's not trivial.  As for (3) being strange, that may be so but this is simply the definition.  Allowing $\lambda=\eta=1$ makes the function cleanly subadditive, quite a strong property.

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant that normally in an F-norm we have nondegeneracy, a weaker homogeneity, subadditivity (so not (3) above), then (4) and (5) are identical.  I'm saying that in that definition you get (5) from the other properties.